# I have asp.net web api with javascript web page, but PUT, DELETE requests don't work properly, though they're fine in SwaggerUI

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

All these requests work with SwaggerUI, but when the app is called with javascript, `PUT` doesn't work at all, and `DELETE` works only after the page is refreshed.

[image: console]

The first `6500b7fc457ae938fd2a0299` is `get{id}` request;
`PUT` is highlighted;
`DELETE` is the last `6500b7fc457ae938fd2a0299`

And this is the index.html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        td {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        button {
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>List of users</h2>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="userId" />
        <p>
            Name:<br />
            <input id="userName" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Age:<br />
            <input id="userAge" type="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <button id="saveBtn">Save</button>
            <button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
        </p>
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead><tr><th>Name<th><th>Age</th><th></th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
    // Getting all users
        async function getUsers() {
            // Sending request and receiving response
            const response = await fetch("/api/Person", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }
            });
            // If response is ok
            if (response.ok === true) {
                // getting data
                const users = await response.json();
                const rows = document.querySelector("tbody");
                // Adding elements to table
                users.forEach(user => rows.append(row(user)));
            }
        }
        // Getting one user
        async function getUser(id) {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/Person/${id}`, {    // index(58)
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }
            });
            if (response.ok === true) {
                const user = await response.json();
                document.getElementById("userId").value = user.id;
                document.getElementById("userName").value = user.name;
                document.getElementById("userAge").value = user.age;
            }
            else {
                // In case of error we receive error message
                const error = await response.json();
                console.log(error.message); //Printing error to console
            }
        }
        //Adding user
        async function createUser(userName, userAge) {

            const response = await fetch("api/Person", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name: userName,
                    age: parseInt(userAge, 10)
                })
            });
            if (response.ok === true) {
                const user = await response.json();
                document.querySelector("tbody").append(row(user));
            }
            else {
                const error = await response.json();
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        }
        // Changing user
        async function editUser(userId, userName, userAge) {
            const response = await fetch("api/Person", {  //index(96)
                method: "PUT",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    id: userId,
                    name: userName,
                    age: parseInt(userAge, 10)
                })
            });
            if (response.ok === true) {
                const user = await response.json();
                document.querySelector(`tr[data-rowid='${user.id}']`).replaceWith(row(user));
            }
            else {
                const error = await response.json();
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        }
        // Deleting user
        async function deleteUser(id) {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/Person/${id}`, { //index 116
                method: "DELETE",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }
            });
            if (response.ok === true) {
                const user = await response.json();
                document.querySelector(`tr[data-rowid='${user.id}']`).remove();
            }
            else {
                const error = await response.json();
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        }

        // Reseting input form after request
        function reset() {
            document.getElementById("userId").value =
            document.getElementById("userName").value =
            document.getElementById("userAge").value = "";
        }
        // Adding row to table
        function row(user) {

            const tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tr.setAttribute("data-rowid", user.id);

            const nameTd = document.createElement("td");
            nameTd.append(user.name);
            tr.append(nameTd);

            const ageTd = document.createElement("td");
            ageTd.append(user.age);
            tr.append(ageTd);

            const linksTd = document.createElement("td");

            const editLink = document.createElement("button");
            editLink.append("Change");
            editLink.addEventListener("click", async() => await getUser(user.id));
            linksTd.append(editLink);

            const removeLink = document.createElement("button");
            removeLink.append("Delete");
            removeLink.addEventListener("click", async () => await deleteUser(user.id));

            linksTd.append(removeLink);
            tr.appendChild(linksTd);

            return tr;
        }
        // Reseting form
        document.getElementById("resetBtn").addEventListener("click", () =>  reset());

        // Sending form
        document.getElementById("saveBtn").addEventListener("click", async () => {

            const id = document.getElementById("userId").value;
            const name = document.getElementById("userName").value;
            const age = document.getElementById("userAge").value;
            if (id === "")
                await createUser(name, age);
            else
                await editUser(id, name, age);
            reset();
        });

        // getting users
        getUsers();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```